# Cancel animations in UITableView while scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am a bit confused and don't have much else to turn to. I have an iOS application that gets messages from a server and populates it into a cell in a UITableView. Every time a certain object gets updated from the server that update triggers a cell animation. In our case we have  a table of scores in a game. If someone loses a point their cell would flash red and if they gain a point their cell would flash green. Simple concept that works well and our users like the feedback. What they don't like is how when they scroll they see the cells have random colors associated with it and stay there for about a second. I believe that it has something to do with the way that the cells are being recycled. I tried various checks regarding this issue, checking that the cell has the same value, setting the color manually to white, etc. and non of these methods work.

All in all I am trying to only show the animation when the cell has been in view and not when the users is scrolling through the UITableView. Anyone have any advice or ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You could cancel the animation before it gets reused by calling `removeAllAnimations` on the animating layer inside `prepareForReuse` for your custom UITableViewCell class.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I still saw all of the cells with assorted colors.

Comment: Are you doing the animations with Core Animation or UIView animations? Is it looking like `[CABasicAnimation animationForKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"]; ...` or looking like `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{ /* change color */ }];`?

Comment: I am doing it using UIView animations.

Comment: Can't you just set the background color to your default color in prepareForReuse then?

Comment: Don't I need to somehow trigger a cancel animation event beforehand?

Comment: Why don't you try it out. I don't think you need to cancel your UIView animations. Changing the value of the animated property should be enough.

Comment: This made it work nicely. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What is happening

Since table views reuse their cells you are ending up reused cells that is being flashed even though they shouldn't.

### How to solve it

You can restore the reused cell to its default state either in `preprareForReuse:` on the custom table view cell or in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method (as [ACB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1730272/acb) mentioned).

Since you are animating with UIView animations, you only need to change the value of the animated property to cancel the animation and return to the default state.

#### If you would have user Core Animation for the flash

If the animation was done using Core Animation you would instead have called `removeAllAnimations` on the animating layer. (For a flashing animation you probably wouldn't change the property on the layer, instead you would tell the animation to autoreverse. This would mean that removing the animation would change the color back to its original value.)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to remove the animation and reset the color in `willDisplayCell` delegate method to the default color. If that doesn't work you can set the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` as follows,

```
NSString *aCellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:aCellIdentifier];
```

But this will be a problem if you have a lot data to display as it will create memory issues. Note that in this case you will not be reusing the table cells.

Comment: Nope that didn't work. I would also like to try avoiding dequeuing the cells as I feel that even though I don't have much data, over time the memory issue would get out of hand.